# Can an app post in a facebook group

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I want to learn how to make a facebook app, but I am not sure it is possible to do what I want. I know it is possible in an app to post messages on the user's wall. I want to know if it is also possible to post a message in a facebook group the user is member of ?

And what do you recommend: javascript or php app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  See the documentation here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/group/feed

Use whichever solution best meets your needs and is easiest for you to code.  Both solutions can post to that edge.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible but in the login you need to add the permission: "publish_actions" for publish in groups, if you want to get the list groups you need the "user_groups" permission, but its a lot of troubles to get approval from facebook, because you need to send an explanation of how you use it, and finally you will reject, so you need to get another way to get the group list.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/group/feed

```
/* PHP SDK v5.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'POST',
  '/{group-id}/feed',
  array (
    'message' => 'This is a test message',
  )
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
```

OR JAVASCRIPT

```
 /* make the API call */
    FB.api(
        "/{group-id}/feed",
        "POST",
        {
            "message": "This is a test message"
        },
        function (response) {
          if (response && !response.error) {
            /* handle the result */
          }
        }
    );
```

You can use javascript in your frontend and php in your backend. It depends what do you need or what you want. If you want to make schedule publications i suggest PHP + cronjobs, but if you